# 'Line2D' object has no property 'tlim'

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

```
import numpy as np 
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t,y = symbols('t,y')
y = symbols('y',cls=Function)
y(t)

deq1 = Eq( y(t).diff(t,2)+10*y(t).diff(t)+9*y(t),0)
deq2 = Eq( y(t).diff(t,2)+6*y(t).diff(t)+9*y(t),0)
deq3 = Eq( y(t).diff(t,2)+y(t).diff(t)+9*y(t),0)

psol1 = dsolve(deq1,ics= {y(0):0.16,y(t).diff(t).subs(t,0):0})
psol2 = dsolve(deq2,ics= {y(0):0.16,y(t).diff(t).subs(t,0):0})
psol3 = dsolve(deq3,ics= {y(0):0.16,y(t).diff(t).subs(t,0):0})

plt.plot(psol1.rhs,tlim=(0,10),ylim=(-0.1,0.15))
plt.plot(psol2.rhs,tlim=(0,10),ylim=(-0.1,0.15))
plt.plot(psol3.rhs,tlim=(0,10),ylim=(-0.1,0.15))

plt.show
```

How can I combine graphs into one table?
An error of 'Line2D' object has no property 'tlim' is displayed.

Comment: `plt.show` is just a function object. You're not calling it

Comment: It's likey xlim, not tlim

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there's an argument called tlim?

Comment: Since it is a function of time, t is used. Even if I fix it with plt.show(), the same error still appears.

Comment: The main issue is that you are directly calling matplotlib's plot with sympy objects.  Matplotlib (nor numpy) doesn't understand about sympy's symbolic expressions.  You need to plot via sympy's plot interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can either SymPy's `plot` function:

```
plot(psol1.rhs, psol2.rhs, psol3.rhs, (t, 0, 10))
```

Or you can use Matplotlib directly if you need more flexibility for customizing the appearance. In this case you'd have to convert the symbolic expressions to numerical functions with `lambdify`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f1 = lambdify([t], psol1.rhs)
f2 = lambdify([t], psol2.rhs)
f3 = lambdify([t], psol3.rhs)
tn = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(tn, f1(tn), label="psol1")
plt.plot(tn, f2(tn), label="psol2")
plt.plot(tn, f3(tn), label="psol3")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: My English is awkward, so the question must have been strange, but thank you for answering!

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the answer to your question if it satisfied your needs.